# validate for a 2-digit number

Tags: powershell

I need to in powershell

-Ask the user for a 2-digit number

-Validate this number is two numeric digits

-Take into account leading zeroes

-If the number is invalid, have the user try again

It seemed that using

```
$2digit = read-host

$2digit -match "[0-9][0-9]"
```

was working but it stopped out of nowhere. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting an a false result when you entered more than 2 characters.
eg: [image]
This is because you have not specified length.

**Resolution**:

```
$2digit = read-host
($2digit.Length -le 2) -and ($2digit -match "[0-9][0-9]")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your regex pattern

`$2digits -match "^[0-9][0-9]$"`

^ - start of string or line

$ - end of string or line

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out

```
do{
do {
  write-host -nonewline "Enter the two digit number: "
  $2d = read-host
  $value = $2d -as [Double]
  $ok = $value -ne $NULL
  if ( -not $ok ) { write-host "!!ERROR:You must enter numeric values!!" }
}
until ( $ok )


  if ($2d.Length -eq 2){$holder = $true}
  elseif($2d.Length -ne 2){Write-host "!!ERROR:The number must be 2 digits!!"}
}
while ( $holder -ne $true )
```

The first do loop will verify that the input is numeric and the second do loop will check it to be 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](http://regexstorm.net/reference) are your friend.  This will only accept digits 0-9 with a length of two.  Anything else will not be accepted.

```
do {
    $input = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the two digit number(0-9)'

    if ( $input -match '^\d{2}$' ) {
        break
    }

    Write-Host "The value must be a two digit number; $input is invalid"
} while ( $true )
```